# FTP I/O Error Ubuntu VM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, azure, ftp, virtual-machine

I have an Ubuntu 12.1 VM running on Windows Azure. I've been trying to connect via FTP to upload files to the VM but I'm having problems.

I installed and set up vsftpd, like is outlined [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/ftp-server.html) (and [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-on-ubuntu-12-04)). I have an Endpoint for FTP defined in Azure for port 21.

I can connect to the VM fine via SSH - that works perfectly. I **cannot** connect via SFTP. I **can** connect via FTP - but it will only list the files on the server, it won't allow me to upload or download files. If I try and upload or download files, I get an I/O error and the connection times out.

Can anyone suggest where the problem may be here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this was a [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/) problem. Turns out you can connect with SFTP just fine as standard (which makes sense I could SSH into it...), but Cyberduck couldn't connect for some reason. Will notify them there.

If anyone else is having that problem, just switch to [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) or some other client and it should work fine.